# Questions about terminology (transpositions)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, finite-groups

> A cycle with only two elements is called a transposition. For example, the permutation of $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ that sends $1$ to $1$, $2$ to $4$, $3$ to $3$ and $4$ to $2$ is a transposition (specifically, the transposition that swaps $2$ and $4$).

Is transposition a $2$-cycle or a permutation that contains a $2$-cycle?

The cycle $(2, 4)$ is not the same as the permutation $(1)(3)(24)$, is it?

> The sign of a simple transposition ($2$-cycle) ($i$ $i+1$)
>   is $-1$.

What does $i$ above stand for? Any natural number? Suppose $i = 3$, then ($i$ $i+1$) = $(34)$ which is a $2$-cycle. Does that make sense?

Comment: $(2\, 4) = (1)(3)(2\, 4)$. Usually if an element is sent to itself then it is omitted in cycle notation. A transposition is a 2-cycle. A permutation containing a transposition that is not a 2-cycle looks like $(1\, 2\, 3)(4\, 5)$, which contains the transposition $(4\, 5)$. For your second question, $i$ denotes any number $1 \leq i \leq n-1$ if we are in the symmetric group $S_n$.

Comment: Yes, it is a $2-$cycle. It has order two, every other permutation is a product of transpositions and disjoint transpositions conmute trivially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transposition is a $2$-cycle. It exchanges two elements in a permutation. $(1)(3)(24)=(24)$ because "$1$-cycles" are really just the identity permutation.

$(i\ i+1)$ is the transposition that transposes $i$ and $i+1$ in $S_n$, where $i<n$.

Comment: Are transpositions $(45)$  and $(54)$ equal?

Comment: @user253061 Yes. Order in general matters in cycle notation, but cyclic permutation preserves the cycle (for example, $(123)=(312)=(231)$). Cyclic permutation for transpositions is just switching the two numbers, so the cycle remains the same.